# dotnet build project.csproj still searching directories

Tags: .net-core

I am trying to build a single project using dotnet build when there are other project files in the directory tree.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build?tabs=netcore2x),

> Arguments
>   PROJECT
>   The project file to build. If a project file is not specified, MSBuild
>   searches the current working directory for a file that has a file
>   extension that ends in proj and uses that file.

Yet, when I run

```
dotnet build project.csproj -c Release
```

all directories are searched recursively, and it tries to build all the projects for which it finds .csproj files.

In my case, there is project.csproj in the root directory.  Five directory levels down, there are three other .csproj files.  Here's what the files look like, names changed:

1. ./project.csproj
2. ./scriptlibrary/Projects/project1/dir1/dir2/project2.csproj
3. ./scriptlibrary/Projects/project1/dir1/dir3/project3.csproj
4. ./scriptlibrary/Projects/project1/dir1/dir4/project4.csproj

When I run

```
dotnet build project.csproj -c Release
```

it finds the other .csproj files and tries to build them.  project.csproj has no dependencies on the other projects.

This doesn't seem to be consistent with the documentation.  What can I do to constrain the build to the single project I specify, on the command line?

Comment: Can you share a log? does it try to build the project files or does it just include all the .cs files? latter one is to be expected unless you set up exclude patterns for the top-level project

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are two  possible solutions to this problem:

1. Refactor your folder structure to exclude projects from subfolders. That will require new `.sln` for your projects.

   ./**Main**/project.csproj

   ./scriptlibrary/Projects/project1/dir1/dir2/project2.csproj
   ./scriptlibrary/Projects/project1/dir1/dir3/project3.csproj
   ./scriptlibrary/Projects/project1/dir1/dir4/project4.csproj
2. In case you cant do that you can exclude subfolders from the compilation by adding `<DefaultItemExcludes>` property item into `project.csproj`:

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>
       <DefaultItemExcludes>scriptlibrary\Projects\*</DefaultItemExcludes>   
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```

   That will enforce compiler to exclude specified subfolders from  compilation and other projects will not be compiled in scope of project.csproj